# Fiddler - Capture and decrypt HTTPS traffic from iPad app

Tags: ios, ipad, ssl, https, fiddler

I'm trying to monitor the HTTPS requests/responses for my iPad app using Fiddler.  I have a Windows 7 PC running Fiddler and have configured the HTTP proxy on my iPad to point to the PC using port 8888.  This works fine and the CONNECT tunnel messages and 'ClientHello' handshakes can be seen in the capture log.  However as soon as I enable the 'Decrypt HTTPS traffic' option in Fiddler, the app is blocked from connecting to the server.  I've tried installing the Fiddler root certificate on the PC, and I also installed the certificate on my iPad by exporting the certificate to a URL and pointing Safari to the URL on my iPad which then installed it.  This hasn't made a difference.  Do I need to do something with the SSL certificate installed at the server running my web service?

Comment: I have the same issue. Oddly, I was able to connect to HTTPS sites with Fiddler decryption enabled the first time I tried it. But then I disabled and re-enabled it, and now it won't work. Even after resetting the Fiddler certs and re-installing the Fiddler root certificate on the iPhone, iOS refuses to connect to any HTTPS sites.

Answer (score 3):

Download the Fiddler Add-on for iOS/Android then visit `http://[proxyip]:[port]/` using your phone browser. You can generate/download your **working** certificate from there.

And

Turn on your fiddler certificate at **Your iPhone Setting -> General -> About -> Certificate Trush Settings**

Answer (score 2):

You may not have completely installed the Fiddler certificate.

Email the fiddler certificate to your iPad.  Open the email and then open the certificate.  iOS will prompt you to trust the certificate, and then install it.

If it is installed correctly, you will have a new iOS setting under `Settings->General->Profile` called DO_NOT_TRUST_Fiddler.  That setting is your installed certificate.

Once the certificate is installed - Fiddler will be able to show you your HTTPS traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I try to open https://github.com for testing. And I have done as Josh said(Install the certificate through email). But I came across "Safari cannot open the page because it cannot establish a secure connection to the server". When I  close http proxy, https;//github.com shows up well.

Answer (score 0):

Install "CertMaker Add-on" from [this](http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-08-19/faq---certificates-in-fiddler) article and try again everything you described in your question - it will work okay.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Even after installing the cert maker add-on, resetting Fiddler's certificates, and reinstalling the root cert on the device, iOS still refuses to connect.

Comment: What app do you try? Some applications use strict verification of certificate and as I understand there is no way to trick them (especially, bank applications). Safari must work okay.